# Typesetting unicode phonetic signs

Tags: xetex, unicode, linguistics, tipa

[This discussion](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.linguistics/1441) says that to use unicode phonetic signs one needs the following:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[T1]{tipa}
\usepackage[tipa]{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

fə'nɛtiks

\end{document}
```

Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compile with `xelatex` or `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Doulos SIL}% or your preferred font for phonetics
\begin{document}
fə'nɛtiks
\end{document}
```

With `xelatex` or `lualatex`, you don’t load `fontenc` or `inputenc`, your source must be utf-8, and you can use any unicode-encoded truetype or opentype font that has the symbols you need.

Comment: If you like Charis SIL for linguistics, note that a new version was released on 2014-10-28 (http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?item_id=CharisSIL_download).